# C# code showing multiple removeable drives window 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows, drive, removable-storage

Below is the C# code that I'm using to get all the removeable drives and then populate the `combobox` with this list:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
                .Where(drive => drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable).ToList();
```

The code works perfectly but with one exception, it shows two removable drives in the combo box while I've attached only one.

Is there any way that I can get only one i.e. the one I've attached at the USB port. I'm using Windows 8 OS.

Comment: What other drive does it detect? A CD, a what?

Comment: I checked it in my computer, I was able to find this hidden drive F:\

Comment: And what type of drive is it?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Removeable Drive!

But I have attatched only one removable drive.

Comment: What actual type of drive is it?

Comment: In properties, it is showing Removable Disk!

Comment: Try adding ` && drive.TotalSize > 0` to your query.

Comment: Adding it throws an IOException.

Comment: You could try WMI: `var removableDrives = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Caption, DeviceID FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'").Get()`.

Comment: or if you want to test download sysinternalsuite and it has a tiny application called bginfo which lists all WMI classes and allows you to query them , pretty cool tool for to learn about WMI classes

Comment: Do you have a card reader by any chance? Those show up in the explorer but actually have no media. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `drive.IsReady`

*Hopes you are making Removal Drive Security!!!!*

**Try this**

```
 comboBox1.DataSource = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
            .Where(drive => drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable && drive.IsReady).ToList()
```

**thanks**

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance oh sorry , just want to make him a clear view that's al; :D

Comment: @7-isnotbad sorry, I couldn't understand the point "Hopes you are making removal Drive Security!" Would you please explain it a bit?

Comment: @Kamran Ahmed Seen Antivirus* as the form name :D

Comment: @7-isnotbad hahahaha just to brag in front of my noob friends ;)

Comment: @Kamran Ahmed if the answer helped Accept it :D

Comment: Yeah sure, the answer helped. :P But I am still waiting for your answer to the above comment 

**I couldn't understand the point "Hopes you are making removal Drive Security!" Would you please explain it a bit?**

Comment: @Kamran Ahmed I Seen Antivirus* as the form name :D so i Hoped tht you are making  A SOFTWARE LIKE Removal Drive Security